# Is it possible to add drop down list using data from multiple sheets in Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on inventory management using Google spreadsheet. There are 5 sheets within the same spreadsheet. I want to create a drop down list in sheet 5 using data from sheets 1-4. I manage to create the drop down list if I use data from one sheet only. How can I create the drop down list which include all the data from multiple sheets? Do I need to use Google Apps script?

The link to first image (shows all sheets):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ENWeKI9Lcmg4ynz4LV6mnvP0opdMSArf/view?usp=sharing

The link to second image (shows sheet which I will add drop down list):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NgBDqHH0f7z5KA07wSVAylJ4WcMnAvPR/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You may create a drop-down list after you join the columns from different worksheet into single column then refer to the column as list, here is formula to join multiple columns into single column:

```
={QUERY(C:C,"Select C where C is not null");QUERY(B:B,"Select B where B is not null")}
```

The original worksheet has two columns with different values that you want to combine it into a single column only, after it is done then you can add Column D as drop down lists for values from both Col B & Col C.

[image]

Comment: I get your point. But I have some other issues. (1) After I create the drop down list in the sheet 5 (titled 'Item received'), I put the quantity received respected to the item I've select from the drop down list. Basically the current stock in sheet 1-4 will automatically add after I update sheet 5 with items received and its quantity. I'm not really sure if this will be affected after I join the column in another sheet. (2) I wish I didn't have to add another sheet in this spreadsheet. I'll really appreciate if you have any idea regarding this.

Comment: Try explain with same image of your data, I find it difficult to understand your scenario with pure text...

Comment: I already edit my question and attached links to my images since I cannot embedded image into my question

Comment: The drop down list is one thing, auto-update qty  is another issue, here I will only solve the drop-down list from multiple spreadsheet only. There is limitation in the data validation itself, you can't use formula inside the selected range also, if you feel that adding new column for combine list look bad solution, there is nothing I can do about that, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for your solution to combine the column. Really appreciate it. I may use that approach later. Thank you.